# Why is the prefix repeated in brackets in the word "((meta-)meta-)meta-design"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, ambiguity, grammaticality-in-context, word-in-context

While reading an article about web design, I came across the following phrase —  "((meta-)meta-)meta-design systems". I'm well aware what meta-design is, but have problems understanding the usage of "((meta-)meta-)". My first thought was that it belongs to terminology or industry jargon, but google search didn't return anything to confirm this assumption. Are these repetitions of "meta-" used to create exaggeration? If yes, is there any particular reason why brackets are used? Please assist.

Context:

> In 2011 I had my a first quick shot at working on systemized algorithmic web layouts at Prismatic (RIP); then captivated by the 2014 article about Flipboard’s layout algorithm I resolved to shift my design career towards abstractions and work on **((meta-)meta-)meta-design** systems and tools to enable more powerful forms of thought amongst human designers.
>   [Full article](http://www.jon.gold/2016/05/robot-design-school/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A

> meta-design

is an abstraction about design, I think the author's use of

> ((meta-)meta-)meta-design

is to emphasize the layering of abstraction they are interested in since the context is about algorithmic AI generation of websites.  It is not about the *design* of a website, or the *design* of the *design* of the website, but several levels deeper.

The author might have something specific in mind to list three levels of abstraction, also since it is written with precedence "(..)"'s.

Comment: Rather than denoting some sort of precedence, the brackets could just mean that the writer works on meta-design and on meta-meta-design and on meta-meta-meta-design